# Gallery of Images not displaying properly with document.getElementbyId()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So I'm working on a website for my job's store, a sort of gallery of our products.  I've gotten the main web page, cut out the fat, put in the meat, and have tested it numerous times along the way.  Now I am having some troubles with the JQuery not working properly.  I have provided direct links to the JQuery code, a copy of the website itself, and the source code below..

The general layout of the JQuery(or Javascript, I'm not exactly sure which) is:

```
window.onload = function() {

    function displayImage() {
        var mainImg = document.getElementById('Main_IMG');
        var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
        mainImg.src = this.src;
        caption.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    document.getElementById('Zero').onclick = displayImage;
    document.getElementById('One').onclick = displayImage;
    document.getElementById('Two').onclick = displayImage;
// Etc etc
}
```

Here is a segment of the website (with some extra fluff removed):

```
<h1 class="Wrapper Main ClearFix">Image Gallery</h1>
<div id="Main" class="Wrapper Main ClearFix">
<div id="container11">
<img id="Main_IMG" src="img/100___06/IMG_0001.JPG" alt=""><br>
<p id="caption"></p>
</div>
<div id="gallary">
<img id="One" src="img/100___06/IMG_0020.JPG" alt="Headboard   Pricing"> 
<img id="Two" src="http://images.craigslist.org/00P0P_84oo9H7byag_600x450.jpg" alt="Needle Point Upholstered Chair   Price: $40"> 
<!-- etc etc -->
```

The program is simple:  When a user clicks on an image (say in a table for example), that image will display to the left of the gallery with the alt tag being the product and price and such.

The problem:  At image number 16 I needed to give it a... different-from-normal tag
(tag I wanted to use: sixteen.
Tag I used: F_sixteen)

The program then worked fine for a few more 'numbers' up until the 36's and 40 where the program refuses to respond properly.

This is a link to the website as of writing this question:[Here](http://ronf.siteground.net/Work/Universal_Services/gallery2.html)

This is a link to the actual jquery code: [Here](http://ronf.siteground.net/Work/Universal_Services/jquery22.js)

And for those on mobile, the link to the source code is: [Here](http://ronf.siteground.net/Work/Universal_Services/gallery_code.txt)

I apologize for the size of this question, as well as if this seems complicated.  Thank you for viewing this, as I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** I am not sure if the web page will work in Safari.  If it doesn't, I'll see what I can do to change it.

Comment: You're not using jQuery `

Comment: Heh heh, shows how much I know about jQuery and Javascript and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I hate to suggest using jQuery to someone who bravely is not. But use it. You can cut out the 40 calls to `document.getElementById` and reduce the risk of typos. Just include jquery in your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    function displayImage(img) {
        var mainImg = document.getElementById('Main_IMG');
        var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
        mainImg.src = img.src;
        caption.innerHTML = img.alt;
    }

    $("#gallary img").click(function(){
        displayImage(this);
    });
}
```

I've kept the required changes in the above code to a minimum. To 'jquerify' it further you could write this equivalent code instead:

```
$(function(){
    var mainImg = $('#Main_IMG');
    var caption = $('#caption');
    $("#gallary img").click(function(){
        mainImg.attr('src', this.src);
        caption.html(this.alt);
    });
});
```

Comment: A nice suggestion on the refactor, but you don't necessarily need to use javascript to do this.

Comment: You mean jQuery? I agree...it's just slightly harder.

Comment: Yes, nice typo by me now. Yes, it's unfortunate the native `getElementsByClassName` didn't have better support in earlier IE versions. http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname Given the HTML of this particular page though, iterating through all elements inside the `gallary` div would work pretty well.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I'm really tempted. But I gotta go to bed!!

Comment: Where do I put the ajax.googleapis script code?  Do I need to put it in the HTML?

And do I use the ajax.google AND the first code or ajax AND the second code or use just the second or first code?

Comment: You need the ajax.google code (which includes jQuery in your page) - put it inside the `<head>` tag. Then, you can optionally use the first code block OR the second. I'd go for the second, it's better! The first is just to try and help explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the site produces javascript error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementByID'"

Examining the javascript, some of your calls are to `getElementById`, and some to `getElementByID`. Javascript is case-sensitive, you have a typo.

Comment: Yeah, starting at 'T_Thirty-nine'.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for pointing that out. 

As for why the site isn't producing the images.  Trying it on Safari it doesn't seem to load, but Firefox and Chrome result in the correct pages.